# TokenMismatch exception while using post in laravel 5.3 api(used postman chrome extension to test)

Tags: php, api, laravel, post, postman

```
 public function store()
    {
        $input=\Input::all();
        $bear=Bear::create($input);
        return $bear;
   }
```

This is my code for inserting data that will be taken from user,for this I used postman chrome extension.

Comment: Are you submitting the data manually by creating a POST request and a body in Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making an API call make sure to add the endpoint URL to your Middleware app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except_urls = [
        '/store',
    ];
```

replace "store" with your own endpoint

Comment: This is dangerous if it gets forgotten and pushed to production.

Comment: No It's not, that's how you have to do it, of course on API calls in production you should implement JWT or something like that.